# Table Level Concurrency in NHibernate

Tags: c#, sql-server, nhibernate, concurrency

Does NHibernate offer any type of mechanism for table level concurrency?  I know of a lot of different options for row level concurrency, but I can't find anything higher.

For example:
1. Let's say that I read some info from a table.
2. Compute what the next row should be based on that information.
3. And then insert the computed row, **unless** something else has come along and changed information in the table in the meantime.

I know that MS-SQL (which is what I am using) has timestamps that is uses with tables to denote their modification, and I was hoping I could use this with NHibernate somehow.  Any ideas?

Comment: SQL Server timestamps are per-row. There is no direct/simple way to track any modification having occurred to a table. Would S-locking the table be enough for you?

Answer (score 0):

No, NHibernate doesn't support table level concurrency.
I have solved the issue by issuing a normal SQL query in the same session as the rest of the NHibernate operations using the

```
...WITH (TABLOCKX HOLDLOCKX)" syntax.
```

It is kind of a pain, but it also works as expected.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, NHibernate support different types of concurrency. As I can see you've got interested on versioned  or optimistic concurrency models.There's excellent article about it:
http://ayende.com/blog/3946/nhibernate-mapping-concurrency

Comment: That link has entirely to do with row level concurrency!